# How to distribute a cost in a normal distribution

Tags: c#, algorithm, statistics, normal-distribution

I've found guides on programmically getting random numbers that generate a normal; however, I need to spread out a number so that it reflects a normal distribution (in the least calculation time possible).

For example, I have an item that cost $500,000 in year 2050 and I would like to spread it across with a standard deviation of 20 years. This will result in the area under the first standard deviation (year 2030 to 2070) having (68% * $500,000) of the cost.

Is there a formula I can use in my code to achieve this? The only way I can think of right now is using the Box Muller random generator and loop through each dollar to generate the distribution, which is definitely not efficient.

Comment: Try [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the total value under the normal distribution is 1. Therefore, you just need to find out what percentage of the curve accumulates in a certain timeframe and multiply by the total cost.

Instead of a normal distribution, you want the normal CDF (cumulative density function) ([here it is in C#](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/csharp_phi/)).

So, to sum up: to find the cost for a given range of years, you find the normalized values for those years, plug them into the CDF function, and multiply by the total cost:

```
start = (start_year-0.5-median)/stddev;
end = (end_year+0.5-median)/stddev;
cost = total_cost*(Phi(end)-Phi(start));
```